# What is the advantage of creating view in SQL database?

Tags: sql-server

Is there any advantage of creating views for tables in SQL, compared to directly query the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Views help you hide sensitive columns that you don't want to show certain type of users by limiting the degree of exposure to the underlying tables. You can also wrap joined multiple tables into a single view (virtual table) that can easily be queried as a single table.